is the kernel of $\phi(x) = 1 + \sqrt2$ where $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{R} $ a principal ideal
This is an exercise from Artin chapter 12. I found that the kernel of $\phi$ is principal, as because we are in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if $ 1 + \sqrt2$ is a root, so much be $1 - \sqrt2$. Taking $(x-1-\sqrt2)(x-1+\sqrt2)$ we see that $x^2-2x-1$ is in the kernel , and similarly if some polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is in the kernel, it must be divisible by $x^2-2x-1$ and thus the kernel is the principal ideal generated by $(x^2-2x-1). $
Please correct me if this is wrong, but this is not necessarily what I had a question about.
My question is more so, with this logic, wouldn't the kernel of every homomorphism of the form $\phi(x) = a + \sqrt b$ with $\phi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $b \geq 0$ and b is not a perfect square and $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a principal ideal and be generated by $((x-a+\sqrt b)(x-a- \sqrt b))$?
Additionally, what about if $a$ is not an in integer, i.e. the homomorphism $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt2$? How would that be generated considering it's not an integer? This would not be a principle ideal then right?

Try to get to your question first, even if you then immediate go to the special case. A lot of readers will be thinking about the "false question," while reading. You can just ask the real question, the launch int9 the Artin question.

And you need to add to your  "real" question that  $b$ is not a perfect square, but otherwise, you are correct.

Ok yes I realised that right as I posted it that it couldn't be a perfect square. Thank you for the answer

Of course, if you allow $\phi:\mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb C,$ the same is true for $b<0.$

Also,  you should have specified $a,b$ integers.

Yes that was my mistake, thank you
